# Helios 44-3 mounted on Canon 5D. Did I get the wrong adapter?

Tags: lens-adapter, adapter, canon-ef, m42

In the mail today I received from eBay a

- Super Takumar 35mm f/3.5
- Helios 44-3 f/2.0
- M42 to Canon EF mount

I mounted the Super Takumar on my Canon EOS 5D with the adapter, and it operates fine except for the lens being mounted almost 90° lopsided every time. The Helios focus ring works fine until it is mounted, then it becomes immovable. If I try a little harder, the lens just unscrews itself from the adapter.

Do I need to buy another kind of adapter (if so which?) or is there something I am not understanding?

[image: Backside of lenses]
(Helios on left, Takumar on right)
[image: Stock photo of same adapter]

Comment: Does the Helios ring become immovable if you only screw the adapter without mounting it on camera?

Comment: Yes, it does. Good catch!

Answer (score 3):

[This thread](http://forum.mflenses.com/helios-44-3-on-canon-eos-problem-solved-t53877.html) on forum.mflenses.com concerns the same issue, and seems to answer the question.

Poster *SonicScot* has the same problem and shows how it is caused by the focus ring extending further than the inner ring on the lens, which is supposed to touch the adapter.

> Clearly the focus ring is in the way of the adapter. I'd like to know if there's a way of moving it.

According to other posters in this thread, this is an issue with some Helios 44-3 lenses. As a result, you are only tightening and loosening the lens from the adapter when rotating the focus ring.

Poster *alex1967* suggests buying a more expensive adapter like the [Rayqual M42 to Canon EOS adapter](http://www.ebay.com/itm/RAYQUAL-M42-SCREW-lens-to-CANON-EOS-Lens-Adapter-/142133407356?hash=item2117cfae7c:g:Tp4AAOSw8gVX7ZYJ).

> Save some money and invest to high quality Rayqual and eliminate the problem. My Helios 44-3, S/N ******* works just fine, but will have the same issue as discussed above with cheap adapter.

Images of that adapter shows it has a hollow front end as opposed to flat on other widely available adapters. Perhaps that will be enough to fit the additional length of the focus ring. However, there is no confirmation that this adapter will work on all Helios 44-3 models and the Rayqual adapter is quite expensive. I have found one [cheaper adapter type](http://www.ebay.com/itm/M42-Lens-to-Canon-EOS-D-SLR-Adapter-Ring-for-60D-700D-7D-6D-5D-Mark-II-III-1200D-/370206208037?hash=item5632027025:g:WuAAAOxyi-ZTba0f) on eBay that has a similar hollow front end, but the hollowness stop a bit further from the edge. Comparing these images with where the focus ring touches the adapter I already have, it's difficult to tell whether either of these adapters will work. It would be a tight fit.

Poster *hpmickey* refers to [this post](http://www.pentaxforums.com/forums/10-pentax-slr-lens-discussion/77158-caution-helios-44-fans-potential-buyers-4.html#post1984654) on pentaxforums.com, suggesting to sand the additional length of the focus ring. That suggestion seems like it would work, but requires making alterations to the focus ring.

**Update**

The cheaper adapter did not work. I misread the picture. It doesn't provide any more room than the other cheap adapters.

Comment: The lens being mounted at uncomfortable angle means that adapter manufacturer did not make the thread at the correct angle. Other adapters may be better at it.

Comment: I have a couple of different adapters coming in the mail, so I will update the answer when I have more information.